# aarch64-linux-android-g++ can't find an exported function

Tags: c++, android-ndk, g++, cross-compiling

everyone. I am using aarch64-linux-android-g++ to compile a binary.
The code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int diag_wakelock_destroy();

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    printf("hello world");
    char mystring[] = "hi";
    int result = diag_wakelock_destroy();

    printf("finish! return: %d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

The function diag_wakelock_destroy is defined in libdiag.so as we can see from IDA or just use "nm -D libdiag.so". But when I compiled it with this command

```
aarch64-linux-android-g++ --sysroot=$SYSROOT -g -fpie -pie -o exe_fine hi_diag.cpp libdiag.so liblog.so libcutils.so libc++.so libm.so libc.so ld-android.so -ldl -L.
```

I got this error.

```
/tmp/ccUb4ImK.o: In function `main':
/home/sam/Documents/test/lib-diag/hi_diag.cpp:13: undefined reference to 
`diag_wakelock_destroy()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So it can't find that exported function! This is weird. Can anyone help me ? Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't it be declared `extern "C"` ?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It's probably because the .so is a C shared library. Thanks!